# How to get rid of N/A from logs forwarded by nxlog?

Tags: nxlog

I have enabled debug mode in windows DNS server and the logfile is located at c:\logs\dns.log

```
<181>Jan  2 11:41:40 DC-SE-01 MSWinEventLog        1        N/A        1011398786        Tue Jan  2 11:41:40 2018        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A                        N/A
<181>Jan  2 11:41:40 DC-IN-01 MSWinEventLog        1        N/A        1011398810        Tue Jan  2 11:41:40 2018        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A                        N/A
<181>Jan  2 11:41:40 DC-IN-01 MSWinEventLog        1        N/A        1011398825        Tue Jan  2 11:41:40 2018        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A        N/A                1/2/2018 11:41:38 AM 0A48 PACKET  00BACCA157DAE01 UDP Snd 11.11.201.81   3b20 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] A      (8)tnmaster(0)        N/A
```

I think these messages are of little importance so how to get rid of these messages from nxlog and why are the "N/A" 's in there ?

Below are relevant parts of nxlog.conf file

```
<Input>
Module im_file
File  "C:\logs\dns.log"
InputType LineBased
Exec $Message=$raw_event; $SyslogFacilityValue=22;
</Input>
<Output logger>
Module om_udp
Host 11.11.11.10
Port 514
Exec to_syslog_snare();
</Output>
<Route 3>
    Path dnsdebug => logger
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Snare syslog format is basically a tab delimited string that assumes certain fields such as the `EventID` since it was primarily designed to transfer the Windows Eventlog over syslog.

In order to generate the output [these fields](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#xm_syslog_proc_to_syslog_snare) need to be populated. When you read the DNS log from a file obviously these fields are not automatically parsed, thus the output has `N/A` at those places.

For more information see the [Snare](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#snare) topic in the NXLog User Guide.
Since you are trying to collect `dns.log` the [Collecting DNS logs](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#windows-server-dns) topic might be also relevant.